# Не могу выполнить запрос на MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!
 Не могу выполнить запрос в MSSQL, пишет ошибку: No column name was specified for column 18 of 't'. No column name was specified for column 18 of 'r'. Не подскажите в чем проблема? Как тогда дать название выборке SELECT?

```
USE QRM
select 
r.Account, 
t.income_rest_rur - case when r.account like '980%' then r.income_rest_rur else r.income_rest_rur/1000 end as income_rest_rur ,
t.income_rest_val - case when r.account like '980%' then r.income_rest_val else r.income_rest_val/1000 end as income_rest_val ,
t.income_rest - case when r.account like '980%' then r.income_rest else r.income_rest/1000 end as income_rest ,
t.turn_db_rur - case when r.account like '980%' then r.turn_db_rur else r.turn_db_rur/1000 end as turn_db_rur ,
t.turn_db_val - case when r.account like '980%' then r.turn_db_val else r.turn_db_val/1000 end as turn_db_val ,
t.turn_db - case when r.account like '980%' then r.turn_db else r.turn_db/1000 end as turn_db ,
t.turn_kr_rur - case when r.account like '980%' then r.turn_kr_rur else r.turn_kr_rur/1000 end as turn_kr_rur ,
t.turn_kr_val - case when r.account like '980%' then r.turn_kr_val else r.turn_kr_val/1000 end as turn_kr_val ,
t.turn_kr - case when r.account like '980%' then r.turn_kr else r.turn_kr/1000 end as turn_kr ,
t.rest_rur - case when r.account like '980%' then r.rest_rur else r.rest_rur/1000 end as rest_rur ,
t.rest_val - case when r.account like '980%' then r.rest_val else r.rest_val/1000 end as rest_val ,
t.rest - case when r.account like '980%' then r.rest else r.rest/1000 end as rest ,
t.Account, t.income_rest_rur, t.income_rest_val, t.income_rest, t.turn_db_rur, 
t.turn_db_val, t.turn_db, t.turn_kr_rur, t.turn_kr_val, t.turn_kr, t.rest_rur, t.rest_val, t.rest, 
r.Account, r.income_rest_rur, r.income_rest_val, r.income_rest, r.turn_db_rur, r.turn_db_val, r.turn_db, 
r.turn_kr_rur, r.turn_kr_val, r.turn_kr, r.rest_rur, r.rest_val, r.rest
from 
(select Begin_d, End_d, Glava, Account, tip, income_rest_rur, income_rest_val, income_rest, turn_db_rur, 
turn_db_val, turn_db, turn_kr_rur, turn_kr_val, turn_kr, rest_rur, rest_val, rest, glava + tip 
from tmp_buh_f101 
where Thousand= 1 and Begin_d=CONVERT(DATETIME, 'BEGIN_DATE', 103) and End_d=CONVERT(DATETIME, 'END_DATE', 103) 
) t
join (
select Begin_d, End_d, Glava, Account, tip, income_rest_rur, income_rest_val, income_rest, turn_db_rur, 
turn_db_val, turn_db, turn_kr_rur, turn_kr_val, turn_kr, rest_rur, rest_val, rest, glava + tip 
from tmp_buh_f101 
where Thousand= 0 and Begin_d=CONVERT(DATETIME, 'BEGIN_DATE', 103) and End_d=CONVERT(DATETIME, 'END_DATE', 103)
) r
on t.account =r.account
order by t.glava, t.tip, t.account
```

Comment: в подзапросах нужно именовать составные/вычисляемые/константные поля. У вас не именовано поле glava + tip в подзапросе t, о чем и сообщается вам в тексте ошибки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как верно заметил @VasilBaymurzin подзапросы вида:

```
(SELECT
  Begin_d,
  End_d,
  Glava,
  Account,
  tip,
  income_rest_rur,
  income_rest_val,
  income_rest,
  turn_db_rur,
  turn_db_val,
  turn_db,
  turn_kr_rur,
  turn_kr_val,
  turn_kr,
  rest_rur,
  rest_val,
  rest,
  glava + tip
FROM tmp_buh_f101
WHERE Thousand = 1
AND Begin_d = CONVERT(datetime, 'BEGIN_DATE', 103)
AND End_d = CONVERT(datetime, 'END_DATE', 103)) t
```

необходимо именовать, в вашем случае он носит имя "t", касаемо ошибки, после форматирования запроса хорошо видно что единственным столбцом не унаследовавшим исходное имя столбца таблицы, является `glava + tip`, указав псевдоним, например `[t_glava_tip]` для этого столбца вы решите проблему.

Настоятельно рекомендую вам фоматировать код, так вы сможете избежать большого количества проблем или существенно ускорить поиск ошибки.

Comment: Вот так  glava + tip AS t_glava_tip если MS SQL?

Comment: @РусланТимербаев, да именно так